# rendr isomorphic framework trigger route

Tags: isomorphic-javascript, rendr

I'd like to trigger a route change via javascript in RendrJS. My use case is that the user is on the `/register` page and upon a successful registration attempt I would like to direct the user to the `/account` page. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice in Rendr is to use `redirectTo` since it's isomorphic.

Inside a controller, we use:

```
this.redirectTo('/some/path');
```

Inside a view, we use:

```
this.app.router.redirectTo('/some/path');
```

Comment: this appears to update the route, call the controller init() method, call the view's init() method, but the DOM contents are not updated. Is there something else I need to do to trigger the DOM update to actually render my subsequent page?

Comment: @jaredrada this is all you need.  You may need to check if you have a javascript/client-side error that is causing something to get interrupted and die before the new page renders.

Comment: my problem was i failed to include the id="content" on the __layout.hbs file! thanks